# jquery mobile popup dialog: Cannot read property 'is' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open dialog box using jquery. I have followed instruction using link: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html

code looks like:
Dialog

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
            <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
            <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
            <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

on jquery ready function, trying to open it through code:
$("#popupDialog").popup();
$("#popupDialog").popup("open");

[getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkZhO.png)

Not sure what is wrong and can not find any help on this!!!

Comment: Have you tried making a very basic popup without all the extra content first? If you can get a very basic stripped down popup working then gradually start adding content to it.

Comment: it works when I use hyper-link to open pop up. ok I will try to open basic pop-up first

Comment: same with the basic pop i have used following code:                                           <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
        </div> but using following code yield same error $().ready(function () {
                    $("#popupBasic").popup();
                    $("#popupBasic").popup("open")});

Comment: Try putting 'document' in to the first brackets, this will make sure all HTML has been fully loaded before running this script.

Answer (score 2):

Open the popup on the jQM pageshow event not the jQuery ready event:

API: http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/pageshow/

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#page1", function(){ 
  $("#popupDialog").popup("open");
});
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/550e4c9t/)**

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it didn't work. Since I want my popup to open after completing Ajax call, there it is working fine. I was just checking my pop-up on page load.